# C++ class access level

Tags: c++, inheritance

Suppose I have two classes. One called Point:

```
class Point{
    public:
        Point(): x_(0), y_(0) {}
    protected: 
        int x_, y_;
    };
```

Then I have another class, which derives from Point:

```
class Point3D : public Point {
public:
    Point3D(): Point(), z_(0){}
    double distance(Point3D pt, Point base) const;
protected:
    int z_;
};

double Point3D::distance(Point3D pt, Point base) const
{
    int dist_x, dist_y;
    dist_x = base.x_ - x_;
    dist_y = base.y_ - y_;

    return sqrt(dist_x * dist_x +
                dist_y * dist_y);
}
```

Then I got error like: base.x_ is protected within this context. But the access level of Point3D to Point is public, plus the x_ data member in Point is protected. So it is supposed to be error-free, right? Can someone please help me clear this out?

Comment: Btw., shouldn't you either use pt instead of this, or remove the parameter pt?

Comment: @deviantfan oh forget about the input parameter pt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But the access level of `Point3D` to `Point` is `public`

That is not entirely true. The protected members of a base class are accessible to a derived class only if they are accessed through a derived class pointer/reference.

```
double Point3D::distance(Point3D pt, Point base) const
{
    int dist_x, dist_y;
    dist_x = base.x_ - x_; // x_ is same as this->x_. Hence it is OK.
                           // base is not a Point3D. Hence base.x_ is not OK.
    dist_y = base.y_ - y_;

    return sqrt(dist_x * dist_x +
                dist_y * dist_y);
}
```

---

Allowing access to `protected` members of a base class through a base class pointer/reference will allow you to change objects in ways that will lead to unintended consequences.

Say you have:

```
class Base
{
   protected:
     int data;
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
    void foo(Base& b)
    {
       b.data = 10; // Not OK. If this were OK ... what would happen?
    }
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
};

int main()
{
    Derived1 d1;
    Derived2 d2;
    d1.foo(d2); 
}
```

If

```
       b.data = 10;
```

were to be allowed in `Derived1::foo`, you are able to modify the state of `d2`, an instance of `Derived2` by `Derived1`. That sort of backdoor modification is not a desirable behavior.

Comment: Thx for the reply. But if you change base.x and base.y to pt.x and pt.y, the code works fine. And the derived class instance pt are accessing the protected base class members without using point/reference, which may contradict your argument. Am I misunderstanding your idea?

Comment: @J.Lin, `pt.x` is ok since `pt` is object of type `Point3D`. That amounts to accessing a `protected` member of the base class using a reference to an object of the derived class type.

Answer (score 1):

The public inheritance mode simply means that the object can access protected members of its base class. In this example, every Point3D object can access the `x_` and `y_` members of Point3D objects only.

However, this does not allow the object to access another Point's protected members from it's base class.

EDIT: As pointed out by J. Lin, simply changing the type of base from Point to Point3D allows the member function to access `x_` and `y_`.

Comment: I think if you change the type of base from Point to Point3D, the code will work fine.